# How to cut a vector at the first negative value

Tags: r

I want to cut a vector on the first negative value, how to do?

```
x <- c(1, 4 , 6 , 3, -1, 4, -3)
```

The operation should result in

```
c(1, 4, 6, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is

```
x[!cumsum(x < 0)]
#[1] 1 4 6 3
```

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which` to find the location of the first negative number, and then subtract 1

```
x[1:(which(x < 0)[1] - 1)]
```

This simple approach will fail if the first number is negative. But we can build a check and return an empty vector as appropriate.

```
cutNeg <- function(x){
  index <- which(x < 0)[1]
  if(index == 1) return(integer(0))
  x[1:(index-1)]
}

cutNeg(x)
```

Comment: If you just remove the parentheses, you won't need the function any more (i.e. `x[1:which(x < 0)[1]-1]`). However, we have two identical solutions posted!

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
x[1:which(x < 0)[1]-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a friend of `cumsum` from @akrun's answer, `cummin` which calculates the cumulative minimum:

```
x[cummin(x) > 0]
[1] 1 4 6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for "-" using grep works as well:

```
x[1:grep("-", x)[1]-1]
```